# How to integrate a modified plugin and all of its dependency plugins in own plugin and deliver it in one thing

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, eclipse-plugin

**Situation:**

I have written an Eclipse plugin which do some stuff.
No I want to use an existing UML Editor plugin which works with my plugin in Eclipse. To modify the UML Editor for my purpose I downloaded the source code of the special plugin and modify some code of it. The Editor itself needs some other plugins, for example the UML2 Extender SDK, GEF etc.

**Goal:**

Is it possible to integrate the modified plugin and all of its dependency plugins in my plugin and deliver it in one thing?

How can I create a feature or a plugin which contains all necessary plugins, so I can give it to a friend who has nothing more to do than for example, put it in his plugin folder and it works without installing some of the necessary plugins in his eclipse additionally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want your friend to manually copy that plugin on his system, that's not a reproducable installation.

Instead you want to create a feature project, which contains your plugin and the modified UML plugin. Your feature project shall have dependencies to the features which you already identified as dependencies.

Additionally you want to create an update site project, which contains your feature and which lists all the update sites of the dependent features as discovery sites. Then you export the update site as archive or really put it online and give your friend the archive or the link. He will install your plugin the normal way using the update manager, and thanks to the included discovery sites, his machine will find all the dependencies and install them directly from the Internet.